# Allow onclick inside an onfocus/onblur show/hide textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the strange title question.

I am wondering how to do the following:

When a user clicks on the blurred out textarea through onfocus, it will display: block the div around it, displaying a "textarea console" and then a "add step" icon beneath the textarea.  If you click out, it will blur the textarea along with two extra items.

However, what I would like to add is, if they click either the "textarea console" or the "add step" icon, the div will not blur out.

Here's what I have so far at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ninacess/wAaDz/5/)

Comment: You have the div wrapped around the textarea?

Comment: hi Ronny. Thanks for checking this out.  I have 3 main parts actually - the "textarea console", the textarea, and then the "prepstepintextarea".  I cleaned it up more.

Comment: Nina, Didnt get what u want acheive though have edited the fiddle check dis one : http://jsfiddle.net/wAaDz/10/

Comment: Hi Dark Rider,  Close, but not what I had in mind yet. When you first run it, it's all hidden. When you click inside the textarea, it reveals the textarea console and the "add step" button.You can click either textarea console and/or the "add step" button. However, when you click outside the div, I would still like the whole section to revert back to being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the jsFiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/MkaKC/)

I think it was just a few things wrong...you were on the right track.

```
$("#textareasteinstruc").focusout(function() {
  alert('focusout');
    $(".textareaconsole").hide();
    $("#addPrepStepButtonicon").hide();
```

The # was missing from focusout function...and classes/IDs were not referenced properly.

It's working the way you want it now I'm thinking :)

UPDATE: I added the $("#addPrepStepButtonicon").show(); to the click event so the 'submit' button will appear again

Comment: But the menu is still hiding after focusout on textarea.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the objective...just change this $(".textareaconsole").show(); in focusout then...to keep the menu.

Comment: Hi timpng1, Is there a way you can get the #addPrepStepButtonicon to hide again if you click away from the div or the #addPrepStepButtonicon?

Comment: Hi Nina - yes, I've updated the Fiddle (forked it) HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/Cg24w/

I've added the focusin event. Let me know if this will work.

Comment: Hi timpng1, I tried it out and if I click on the #addPrepStepButtonicon, it hides it again.  It should allow me to click on the button.  But the area should gray out if I click away from the div.

Comment: jsfiddle is down right now so I can't give an example. Until it's up and running it will be difficult to give a good example because I don't have the code we were working with...in the meantime you could look at [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or if you're using jQuery 1.7 or greater you could use the on()/off() functions to handle which function should fire at what time. Otherwise - you could add a mouseover function to the #addPrepStepButtonicon and do something like $(this).show(); Let me know if this helps...if it does I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/wAaDz/13/ . Have made changes.

Comment: Hi Dark Rider, thanks for trying again. When I click on the button, it'll pop out like it should. However, if I click out of the whole div, it won't hide it again (like the initial blurred event).  Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: Sorry Nina didnt get you, Which button and which initial event?

Comment: Hi Dark Rider, When you first load the page, the textarea, the console, and the add-a-step button are hidden/ grayed out (this is the initial event).  If I click the add-a-step button or the text console, it should popout like you achieved. However, i would like it if I click outside the div, it will blur out the textarea, the console, and the add-a-step button.